Sending custom JSON query combined with other java queries in Java client without wrapper query - Elasticsearch 8
I have some json string that I get from external user which is a black box for me and can contain any DSL query.
In addition, I need to append to this query some other query conditions which I build in Java code.
What I did so far was to transfer the JSON string (that I got from the user) to base64 and use a wrapper query, and create a bool-must query with the wrapper query and my other needed query conditions (what I actually send in the request to elasticsearch is the "finalQuery" in the example).
 List<Query> queries = new ArrayList<>();
//add some required queries for ex: 
 queries.add(RangeQuery.of( rq -> rq.field(field).
                                gte( JsonData.of(minimum)).
                                lte( JsonData.of(maximum)))._toQuery());

//step 2: add wrapper query for the customer query 
String encodedString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(((String) queryStr).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

queries.add(WrapperQuery.of(wq -> wq.query(encodedString))._toQuery());
Query finalQuery = BoolQuery.of(bq -> bq.filter(queries))._toQuery()

My question is:
is this the right way to do it?
it there a better way to send the customer query instead of using Wrapper query with base 64 which seems to hurt the performance?
